# RSpec Test - Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError

Tags: mysql, rspec, rubygems

Looks like my mysql2 gem is having difficulty connecting to a database. I can connect to mysql database easily using other mysql client tools. I checked the database connection string that is used for RSpec and it is correct. I get following error when I run `a_spec.rb` spec file.

```
Failure/Error: @db_client = DBClient.new
     Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError:
       SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
     # ./vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `connect'
     # ./vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `initialize'
     # ./helpers/db_client.rb:9:in `new'
     # ./helpers/db_client.rb:9:in `initialize'
     # ./v1/agent_summary_data_spec.rb:9:in `new'
     # ./v1/agent_summary_data_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
```

I am running following version of mysql in my machine

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.12 for osx10.12 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
```

I am using following gem

```
$ gem which mysql2
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2.rb
```

Any idea what might be going on? Wondering if anybody has faced similar problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the `spec` file here

Comment: Also, the `database.yml` file.

Comment: Thanks @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I am able to solve it. Please see my answer below. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I am able to resolve the above SSL issue. All I did was uninstalled and re-installed mysql2 gem using following commands. It did the magic.

```
bundle exec gem uninstall mysql2

bundle install
```